# Creating a LinkedList

Tags: java, linked-list

If I create a `LinkedList` like this:

```
LinkedList<Integer> Mistery = new LinkedList<>();
```

It will be possible to implement this: `Mistery.getFirst();`

If, on the other hand, I create a LinkedList like this:

```
List<Integer> Mistery = new LinkedList<>();
```

It won't be possible to implement the `getFirst()` method on the `Mistery` list.

Why?

Comment: Good time to learn Inheritance and Instantiation with a parent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List<Integer> Mistery = new LinkedList<>();
```

By declaring the variable this way, you're telling the compiler: I want to use a List. The implementation of the List I want is LinkedList, but the rest of the code shouldn't know about that. All it needs to know is that it's a List. I might change my mind later and use an ArrayList, and the rest of the code would still compile, because ArrayList is also a List. I could also assign another object to the same variable, and this object might be of type ArrayList, or CopyOnWriteArrayList, or any other type of List.

Since List doesn't have a `getFirst()` method, you can't use it: the variable is of type List, not LinkedList. At runtime, sure, the object is of type LinkedList. But the compiler only knows the type of the variable. It doesn't know its concrete type at runtime.

Side note: Java variables should start with a lowercase letter, to respect the standard conventions.

Answer (score 3):

Because you declare the `Mistery` as a super type: `List` (although you picked the `LinkedList` as the implementation) , in `List` interface, there is no `getFirst()` method defined.

Answer (score 1):

Something to think about is also why you would want to use List. (Answers already covering why `List` doesn't have getFirst() method).

Say you have a method that prints content of a list:

```
public printStuff(List list){
   for(Object element: list){
       System.out.println(element);}
```

By declaring your Mistery list a List it means you could then (through `polymorphism`), use a single method for a range of lists i.e.

```
List<Integer> Mistery = new LinkedList<>();
List<Integer> Mistery2 = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> Mistery3 = new ArrayList<>();
//etc
```

Then you can do this:

```
printStuff(Mistery);
printStuff(Mistery2);
printStuff(Mistery3); //can even print out a List which contains Strings
```

If the List was declared like this `LinkedList<Integer> Mistery = new LinkedList<>();` you could **not** use the method `printStuff`. You should also read up on [casting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html).